# Modify HashMap when CompletableFuture is finished

Tags: java, asynchronous, hashmap

I have a multi-module system, where one module handles my database storage. This is the method which saves a document:

```
    public CompletableFuture<?> runTransaction() {
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            TransactionBody txnBody = (TransactionBody<String>) () -> {
                MongoCollection<Document> collection = transaction.getDatabase().getCollection(transaction.getCollection().toString());
                collection.insertOne(session, Document.parse(json));
                return "Completed";
            };
            try {
                session.withTransaction(txnBody);
            } catch (MongoException ex) {
                throw new UncheckedMongoException(ex);
            }
        });
    }
```

the json instance is passed down in the object constructor. However, since this will be used by several modules, with each individual caching system, I'm trying to figure out how the caller can modify data structure, if this method completed without any errors.

For example

```
public void createClan(Transaction transaction, int id, int maxPlayers) {
                MongoTransaction mongoTransaction = (MongoTransaction) transaction;
                Clan clan = new Clan(id, maxPlayers);
                String json = gson.toJson(clan);

                TransactionExecutor executor = new MongoTransactionExecutor(mongoTransaction, json);
                executor.runTransaction(); //Returns the completableFuture instance generated by the method. Modify hashmap here.
        }
```

I've tried reading the docs, however it was a bit confusing, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to update the hashmap with the value returned by the `runTransaction` method? Do you need the hashmap update to be async?

Comment: No, the hashmap saves the "Clan" object created in the createClan method. The Map is a ConcurrentHashMap so it  is thread-safe either way.

Comment: Being async means, you have no guarantee when the HashMap will be updated. Thread safety will not let concurrent threads update and corrupt the map. They both are not the same. Do you want a guarantee as to when the HashMap is updated? And should the update run regardless of what / when the response from `runTransaction` is returned? If yes to both, the next line can be hashmap update.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry. I don't need the hashmap to be updated instantly. I only want the hashmap updated if runTransaction did not generate any errors ( When runTransaction is complete).

Comment: Did you try CompletableFuture#get or CompletableFuture#thenRun on the `runTransaction`?

Comment: Oh. This might work yeah, going to test.

```public void createClan(Transaction transaction, int id, int maxPlayers) {
                MongoTransaction mongoTransaction = (MongoTransaction) transaction;
                Clan clan = new Clan(id, maxPlayers);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(clan);

                TransactionExecutor executor = new MongoTransactionExecutor(mongoTransaction, json);
                executor.runTransaction().thenRun(() -> clans.put(clan.id, clan));
        }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given in the comments, two options can be considered.

First option is to convert the async nature into sync nature using `CompletableFuture#get`. This way, the code execution is in a blocking context.

```java
public void createClan(Transaction transaction, int id, int maxPlayers) {
   MongoTransaction mongoTransaction = (MongoTransaction) transaction;
   Clan clan = new Clan(id, maxPlayers);   
   String json = gson.toJson(clan);
   TransactionExecutor executor = new MongoTransactionExecutor(mongoTransaction, json);
   try {
      Object obj = executor.runTransaction().get();
      // HashMap update here
   } catch(Exception e) {
      //handle exceptions
   }
}
```

Second option is to keep the async nature as is and chain using `thenRun` (there are many `then` options available). This way is more a non-blocking context.

```java
 public void createClan(Transaction transaction, int id, int maxPlayers) {
   MongoTransaction mongoTransaction = (MongoTransaction) transaction;
   final Clan clan = new Clan(id, maxPlayers);   
   String json = gson.toJson(clan);
   TransactionExecutor executor = new MongoTransactionExecutor(mongoTransaction, json);
   try {
      executor.runTransaction().thenRun(() -> updateHashMap(clan));
   } catch(Exception e) {
      //handle exceptions
   }
}
```